# Deleting node from linked list issues C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm simply trying to delete a node from the linked list and seem to be having trouble. I was wondering if someone could please have a look at what could be wrong? Thanks!

```
struct ets {
    struct node *equip_head;
    struct node *member_head;
    struct node *loan_head;

    const char *equip_fname;
    const char *member_fname;
    const char *loan_fname;
};

struct node {
    void *data; /* Accepts all data, yay */
    struct node *next;
};

BOOLEAN deleteMember(struct ets *ets, char MemberID[]) {
    struct node *current = ets->member_head;
    struct node *tmpNode = current;
    struct member_data *member_data = NULL;

    while (current != NULL) {
        member_data = current->data;

        if (strcmp(member_data->MemberID, MemberID) == 0) {
            tmpNode = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(tmpNode->data);
            free(tmpNode);

            return TRUE;
        }

        current = current->next;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: What type of trouble you are getting..?

Comment: `==7798== Invalid read of size 8
==7798==    at 0x40214E: display_members (ets_options.c:177)
==7798==    by 0x400EEE: menu (ets_menu.c:74)
==7798==    by 0x400DC6: menu_init (ets_menu.c:30)
==7798==    by 0x401A84: main (ets_main.c:46)
==7798==  Address 0x51fe030 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==7798==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7798==    by 0x402785: deleteMember (ets_options_extended.c:63)
==7798==    by 0x40259F: delete_member (ets_options.c:282) `

Comment: Which line raises the error, (debugger)?

Comment: @JohnnyDoey You can add that information to your question by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28250108/edit) link under the tags.

Comment: Add the definition of `member_data *member_data` and you are using the same name for structure and its object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not removing the node from list. You can do this to remove a node from a list:

```
BOOLEAN deleteMember(struct ets *ets, char MemberID[]) {
    struct node *current = ets->member_head;
    struct node *prev=NULL;
    struct member_data *member_data = NULL;


    while(current != NULL) {
        member_data = current->data;

        if(strcmp(member_data->MemberID, MemberID) == 0) {

            if(prev==NULL) // removing 1st node
                ets->member_head=current->next;
            else
                prev->next=current->next; // removing current node from list

            free(current->data);
            free(current);

            return TRUE;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a single linked list you delete algorythm is broken. Here is what your are currently doing :

- locate member to delete. Fine. You have `node-1 -> node -> node+1`
- you delete the member. Why not. But you list would become `node-1 -> unallocated node` and no way to find next nodes

You should instead test if next node has the correct id to have something like : `prev_node(current)` -> node_to_delete -> next_node`

Then you can do :

```
tmpNode = current->next;
current->next = tmpNode->next; /* ok for the chaining */
free(tmpNode->data); /* deletion will be ok */
free(tmpNode);
```

With of course a special management for first and last nodes ...

Edit : Ali already gave the answer. I leave this one as a comment on why OP's algo was broken